# Chrome with CSP img-src * still blocks images

Tags: google-chrome, content-security-policy

My webapp has a Content Security Policy that sets img-src to * (load images from anywhere), yet Chrome still blocks some images from loading...

> Refused to load the image
>   'data:image/webp;base64,UklGRhoAAABXRUJQVlA4TA0AAAAvAAAAEAcQERGIiP4HAA=='
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "img-src *". lg @
>   js?libraries=places,geometry&v=3&callback=**async_req_1**:84(anonymous
>   function) @
>   js?libraries=places,geometry&v=3&callback=**async_req_1**:119google.maps.Load
>   @
>   js?libraries=places,geometry&v=3&callback=**async_req_1**:21(anonymous
>   function) @
>   js?libraries=places,geometry&v=3&callback=**async_req_1**:118(anonymous
>   function) @
>   js?libraries=places,geometry&v=3&callback=**async_req_1**:119

If I include 'data:' in the directive, the error is not shown in the console.

img-src * data:;

However, that is not a valid directive.  Is there an img-src valid CSP value that would satisfy Chrome or is this a Chrome bug perhaps?  I was not able to find any direct matches in the accessible bug list.  I'm speculating this might be related to images embedded in SVG files.  Firefox and Safari do not exhibit this behavior.

Comment: What do you mean by "invalid?"

Comment: According to http://content-security-policy.com: "Multiple source list values can be space seperated with the exception of * and none which should be the only value."  This suggests listing both a '*' and 'data:' would be invalid.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

content-security-policy.com is wrong. See [w3.org/TR/CSP2/#source-list-guid-matching](https://w3.org/TR/CSP2/#source-list-guid-matching).

> As defined above, special URL schemes that refer to specific pieces
>   of unique content, such as "data:", "blob:" and "filesystem:" are
>   excluded from matching a policy of * and must be explicitly listed.

* also does not include 'unsafe-inline' or 'unsafe-eval' either.

Comment: Great, the spec rules!  I will add 'img-src: * data:' to the CSP.  (Does order matter?)  I'm deploying to both Desktop and Mobile browsers (some with embedded webviews).  I'll retest, but I remember one of the platforms, perhaps an older Android, rejected this format.  I wonder if the spec has evolved in this area and perhaps some older browsers reflect the older standard.  I'll come back to this trail should I find examples.  Thanks for your answer, oreoshake!

Comment: Nope, order does not matter. Older android browsers (when using x-webkit-csp) had all sorts of problems. I haven't seen any with content-security-policy (but that doesn't mean they don't exist). Kudos to you for going down this path, don't give up! I'm here to help (@ndm and @seeesspee on twitter).